# What is the difference between doAfterSucces and doOnSuccess in Reactor?

Tags: java, rx-java, project-reactor

Reactor has a number of these methods, `doOnSuccessOrError` and `doAfterSuccessOrError` for example.

What is the material difference? The documentation doesn't clarify.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is the matter of timing: "**when** the Mono terminates" and "**after** the Mono terminates". The `doOnSuccessOrError` notifies the handler before the downstream and the `doAfterSuccessOrError` notifies the handler after the downstream receives the respective terminal event.